# Writing with bcpandas fails with errors "Invalid character value for cast specification"

Tags: sql-server, pandas, bcp

I'm writing a Python Pandas dataframe to SQL Server 17 with BCP using the `bcpandas` package.  Pandas 1.5.1, bcpandas 2.6.0.  The write command looks like:

```py
from bcpandas import SqlCreds, to_sql
to_sql(my_df, table_name, my_bcp_creds, if_exists = "replace", index = False, debug = True)
```

As the BCP write occurs, this message prints to the console:

> SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

It prints once for each row that BCP can't write.  Eventually after 5 or 10 of these, the BCP write is aborted, having written 3k of the 80k rows in the Pandas dataframe.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General strategy**

First limit the number of rows of your dataframe being written with e.g., `df.head(11)` until you isolate the first single row where the error message gets thrown.  Save it with `x = df.head(11).tail(1)`.

Then with this one-row dataframe, loop through the columns.  In the loop, for each column, print the column name, then make a copy of the dataframe without that column and write it with BCP to a test destination table.  One of these iterations should succeed without the error, indicating which column had the problematic character.

**My specific case**

In my case, the above strategy revealed that the character `\n` appearing in a comment string was the culprit.  I removed it with a command:

```
df['REVIEW COMMENTS'] = df['REVIEW COMMENTS'].str.replace('\n',' ')
```

After which the BCP write succeeded.